# Can XSLT be improved further?

Tags: python, xml, xslt

I have 2 XSLs:

**GET ID**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:oval="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-common-5"
                xmlns:oval-res="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-results-5"
                xmlns:oval-def="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5"
                xmlns:ind-def="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5#independent" 
                xmlns:unix-def="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5#unix"
                xmlns:linux-def="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5#linux"
                exclude-result-prefixes="oval oval-def oval-res ind-def unix-def linux-def">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="oval-def:definition">
    <xsl:value-of select='@id'/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<!-- include to stop leakage from builtin templates -->
<xsl:template match='node()' mode='engine-results'/>
<xsl:template match="text()"/>
```

**GET TITLE and RESULT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:oval="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-common-5"
                xmlns:oval-res="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-results-5"
                xmlns:oval-def="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5"
                xmlns:ind-def="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5#independent" 
                xmlns:unix-def="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5#unix"
                xmlns:linux-def="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5#linux"
                exclude-result-prefixes="oval oval-def oval-res ind-def unix-def linux-def">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="oval-def:definition">
    <xsl:if test="@id=$defid">
        <xsl:value-of select='oval-def:metadata/oval-def:title'/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="oval-res:system/oval-res:definitions/oval-res:definition">
    <xsl:if test="@definition_id=$defid">
        <xsl:value-of select='@result'/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<!-- include to stop leakage from builtin templates -->
<xsl:template match='node()' mode='engine-results'/>
<xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Some stats**
The source XML file is approximately 50 MB.
The number of IDs in the source file is 2962.
I am using xsltproc on Linux.

I am using a python program to get the all the IDs from the source XML first. Then, for each ID, collecting title and status from the source XML. This transformation is taking approximately 2 hours on a 4 CPU box with 8 GB of RAM.

My question is, is there something that I could do to improve XSLT further to reduce transformation time?

**Sample Source file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<oval_results xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:oval="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-common-5" xmlns="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-results-5" xsi:schemaLocation="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-results-5 oval-results-schema.xsd http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-common-5 oval-common-schema.xsd">
  <generator>
    <oval:product_name>cpe:/a:open-scap:oscap</oval:product_name>
    <oval:product_version>1.2.5</oval:product_version>
    <oval:schema_version>5.10</oval:schema_version>
    <oval:timestamp>2016-08-17T11:43:37</oval:timestamp>
  </generator>
  <directives>
    <definition_true reported="true" content="full"/>
    <definition_false reported="true" content="full"/>
    <definition_unknown reported="true" content="full"/>
    <definition_error reported="true" content="full"/>
    <definition_not_evaluated reported="true" content="full"/>
    <definition_not_applicable reported="true" content="full"/>
  </directives>
  <oval_definitions xmlns:oval="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-common-5" xmlns:unix-def="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5#unix" xmlns:ind-def="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5#independent" xmlns:lin-def="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5#linux" xmlns="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5" xsi:schemaLocation="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5#unix unix-definitions-schema.xsd http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5#independent independent-definitions-schema.xsd http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5#linux linux-definitions-schema.xsd http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5 oval-definitions-schema.xsd http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-common-5 oval-common-schema.xsd">
    <generator>
      <oval:product_name>Enhanced SCAP Content Editor (eSCAPe)</oval:product_name>
      <oval:product_version>1.2.2</oval:product_version>
      <oval:schema_version>5.10</oval:schema_version>
      <oval:timestamp>2015-09-20T02:13:56</oval:timestamp>
    </generator>
    <definitions>
      <definition id="oval:com.vmware.test.linux:def:3" version="1" class="compliance">
        <metadata>
          <title>Rule 3 - /etc/passwd file is group-owned by root</title>
          <affected family="unix">
            <platform>cpe:/o:sles11:linux</platform>
          </affected>
          <description>This rule verifies that /etc/passwd file is group-owned by root.</description>
        </metadata>
        <criteria comment="None">
          <criterion test_ref="oval:com.vmware.test.linux:tst:3" comment="This rule verifies that /etc/passwd file is group-owned by root."/>
        </criteria>
      </definition>
      <definition id="oval:com.vmware.test.linux:def:2" version="1" class="compliance">
        <metadata>
          <title>Rule 2 - /etc/passwd file is owned by root</title>
          <affected family="unix">
            <platform>cpe:/o:sles11:linux</platform>
          </affected>
          <description>This rule verifies that /etc/passwd file is owned by root.</description>
        </metadata>
        <criteria comment="None">
          <criterion test_ref="oval:com.vmware.test.linux:tst:2" comment="This rule verifies that /etc/passwd file is owned by root."/>
        </criteria>
      </definition>
      <definition id="oval:com.vmware.test.linux:def:1" version="1" class="compliance">
        <metadata>
          <title>Rule 1 - /etc/passwd file has permissions of 644 or more restrictive</title>
          <affected family="unix">
            <platform>cpe:/o:sles11:linux</platform>
          </affected>
          <description>This rule verifies that /etc/passwd file has permissions of 644 or more restrictive.</description>
        </metadata>
        <criteria comment="None">
          <criterion test_ref="oval:com.vmware.test.linux:tst:1" comment="This rule verifies that /etc/passwd file has permissions of 644 or more restrictive."/>
        </criteria>
      </definition>
    </definitions>
    <tests>
      <unix-def:file_test id="oval:com.vmware.test.linux:tst:3" version="1" check="all" comment="Default comment, please change">
        <unix-def:object object_ref="oval:com.vmware.test.linux:obj:1"/>
        <unix-def:state state_ref="oval:com.vmware.test.linux:ste:3"/>
      </unix-def:file_test>
      <unix-def:file_test id="oval:com.vmware.test.linux:tst:2" version="1" check="all" comment="This rule verifies that /etc/passwd file is owned by root.">
        <unix-def:object object_ref="oval:com.vmware.test.linux:obj:1"/>
        <unix-def:state state_ref="oval:com.vmware.test.linux:ste:2"/>
      </unix-def:file_test>
      <unix-def:file_test id="oval:com.vmware.test.linux:tst:1" version="1" check="all" comment="This rule verifies that /etc/passwd file has permissions of 644 or more restrictive.">
        <unix-def:object object_ref="oval:com.vmware.test.linux:obj:1"/>
        <unix-def:state state_ref="oval:com.vmware.test.linux:ste:1"/>
      </unix-def:file_test>
    </tests>
    <objects>
      <unix-def:file_object id="oval:com.vmware.test.linux:obj:1" version="1" comment="/etc/passwd file">
        <unix-def:filepath>/etc/passwd</unix-def:filepath>
      </unix-def:file_object>
    </objects>
    <states>
      <unix-def:file_state id="oval:com.vmware.test.linux:ste:3" version="1" comment="This rule verifies that /etc/passwd file is group-owned by root.">
        <unix-def:group_id datatype="int">0</unix-def:group_id>
      </unix-def:file_state>
      <unix-def:file_state id="oval:com.vmware.test.linux:ste:2" version="1" comment="This rule verifies that /etc/passwd file is owned by root.">
        <unix-def:user_id datatype="int">0</unix-def:user_id>
      </unix-def:file_state>
      <unix-def:file_state id="oval:com.vmware.test.linux:ste:1" version="1" comment="This rule verifies that /etc/passwd file has permissions of 644 or more restrictive.">
        <unix-def:uexec datatype="boolean">false</unix-def:uexec>
        <unix-def:gwrite datatype="boolean">false</unix-def:gwrite>
        <unix-def:gexec datatype="boolean">false</unix-def:gexec>
        <unix-def:owrite datatype="boolean">false</unix-def:owrite>
        <unix-def:oexec datatype="boolean">false</unix-def:oexec>
      </unix-def:file_state>
    </states>
  </oval_definitions>
  <results>
    <system>
      <definitions>
        <definition definition_id="oval:com.vmware.test.linux:def:3" result="true" version="1">
          <criteria operator="AND" result="true">
            <criterion test_ref="oval:com.vmware.test.linux:tst:3" version="1" result="true"/>
          </criteria>
        </definition>
        <definition definition_id="oval:com.vmware.test.linux:def:2" result="true" version="1">
          <criteria operator="AND" result="true">
            <criterion test_ref="oval:com.vmware.test.linux:tst:2" version="1" result="true"/>
          </criteria>
        </definition>
        <definition definition_id="oval:com.vmware.test.linux:def:1" result="true" version="1">
          <criteria operator="AND" result="true">
            <criterion test_ref="oval:com.vmware.test.linux:tst:1" version="1" result="true"/>
          </criteria>
        </definition>
      </definitions>
      <tests>
        <test test_id="oval:com.vmware.test.linux:tst:1" version="1" check="all" result="true">
          <tested_item item_id="1312221" result="true"/>
        </test>
        <test test_id="oval:com.vmware.test.linux:tst:2" version="1" check="all" result="true">
          <tested_item item_id="1312221" result="true"/>
        </test>
        <test test_id="oval:com.vmware.test.linux:tst:3" version="1" check="all" result="true">
          <tested_item item_id="1312221" result="true"/>
        </test>
      </tests>
      <oval_system_characteristics xmlns:oval="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-common-5" xmlns:unix-sys="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-system-characteristics-5#unix" xmlns:ind-sys="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-system-characteristics-5#independent" xmlns:lin-sys="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-system-characteristics-5#linux" xmlns="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-system-characteristics-5" xsi:schemaLocation="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-system-characteristics-5 oval-system-characteristics-schema.xsd http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-system-characteristics-5#independent independent-system-characteristics-schema.xsd http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-system-characteristics-5#unix unix-system-characteristics-schema.xsd http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-system-characteristics-5#linux linux-system-characteristics-schema.xsd http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-common-5 oval-common-schema.xsd">
        <generator>
          <oval:product_name>cpe:/a:open-scap:oscap</oval:product_name>
          <oval:schema_version>5.10</oval:schema_version>
          <oval:timestamp>2016-08-17T11:43:36</oval:timestamp>
        </generator>
        <system_info>
          <os_name>Linux</os_name>
          <os_version>#1 SMP Thu Mar 26 10:55:49 UTC 2015 (0e3c7c8)</os_version>
          <architecture>x86_64</architecture>
          <primary_host_name>vROPS_6-1</primary_host_name>
          <interfaces>
            <interface>
              <interface_name>lo</interface_name>
              <ip_address>127.0.0.1</ip_address>
              <mac_address>00:00:00:00:00:00</mac_address>
            </interface>
            <interface>
              <interface_name>lo</interface_name>
              <ip_address>127.0.0.2</ip_address>
              <mac_address>00:00:00:00:00:00</mac_address>
            </interface>
            <interface>
              <interface_name>eth0</interface_name>
              <ip_address>10.112.56.130</ip_address>
              <mac_address>00:50:56:93:61:59</mac_address>
            </interface>
            <interface>
              <interface_name>lo</interface_name>
              <ip_address>::1</ip_address>
              <mac_address>00:00:00:00:00:00</mac_address>
            </interface>
            <interface>
              <interface_name>eth0</interface_name>
              <ip_address>fe80::250:56ff:fe93:6159</ip_address>
              <mac_address>00:50:56:93:61:59</mac_address>
            </interface>
            <interface>
              <interface_name>sit0</interface_name>
              <ip_address>::10.112.56.130</ip_address>
              <mac_address>00:00:00:00:00:00</mac_address>
            </interface>
            <interface>
              <interface_name>sit0</interface_name>
              <ip_address>::127.0.0.2</ip_address>
              <mac_address>00:00:00:00:00:00</mac_address>
            </interface>
            <interface>
              <interface_name>sit0</interface_name>
              <ip_address>::127.0.0.1</ip_address>
              <mac_address>00:00:00:00:00:00</mac_address>
            </interface>
          </interfaces>
        </system_info>
        <collected_objects>
          <object id="oval:com.vmware.test.linux:obj:1" version="1" flag="complete">
            <reference item_ref="1312221"/>
          </object>
        </collected_objects>
        <system_data>
          <unix-sys:file_item id="1312221" status="exists">
            <unix-sys:filepath>/etc/passwd</unix-sys:filepath>
            <unix-sys:path>/etc</unix-sys:path>
            <unix-sys:filename>passwd</unix-sys:filename>
            <unix-sys:type>regular</unix-sys:type>
            <unix-sys:group_id datatype="int">0</unix-sys:group_id>
            <unix-sys:user_id datatype="int">0</unix-sys:user_id>
            <unix-sys:a_time datatype="int">1471360413</unix-sys:a_time>
            <unix-sys:c_time datatype="int">1471360395</unix-sys:c_time>
            <unix-sys:m_time datatype="int">1463992525</unix-sys:m_time>
            <unix-sys:size datatype="int">1254</unix-sys:size>
            <unix-sys:suid datatype="boolean">false</unix-sys:suid>
            <unix-sys:sgid datatype="boolean">false</unix-sys:sgid>
            <unix-sys:sticky datatype="boolean">false</unix-sys:sticky>
            <unix-sys:uread datatype="boolean">true</unix-sys:uread>
            <unix-sys:uwrite datatype="boolean">true</unix-sys:uwrite>
            <unix-sys:uexec datatype="boolean">false</unix-sys:uexec>
            <unix-sys:gread datatype="boolean">true</unix-sys:gread>
            <unix-sys:gwrite datatype="boolean">false</unix-sys:gwrite>
            <unix-sys:gexec datatype="boolean">false</unix-sys:gexec>
            <unix-sys:oread datatype="boolean">true</unix-sys:oread>
            <unix-sys:owrite datatype="boolean">false</unix-sys:owrite>
            <unix-sys:oexec datatype="boolean">false</unix-sys:oexec>
            <unix-sys:has_extended_acl datatype="boolean">false</unix-sys:has_extended_acl>
          </unix-sys:file_item>
        </system_data>
      </oval_system_characteristics>
    </system>
  </results>
</oval_results>
```

**Output of Python program**

```
[
    {
        "Status": "true",
        "Title": "Rule 3 - /etc/passwd file is group-owned by root",
        "RuleID": "oval:com.vmware.test.linux:def:3"
    },
    {
        "Status": "true",
        "Title": "Rule 2 - /etc/passwd file is owned by root",
        "RuleID": "oval:com.vmware.test.linux:def:2"
    },
    {
        "Status": "true",
        "Title": "Rule 1 - /etc/passwd file has permissions of 644 or more restrictive",
        "RuleID": "oval:com.vmware.test.linux:def:1"
    }
]
```

Comment: I think to have any hope of a meaningful answer you must include some sample input XML and the corresponding desired output XML.  Also show the COMPLETE xsllt files.

Comment: I know that. We need to see actual samples. Also I doubt you need to use two passes. Read up on `<xsl:key.../>` and the `key()` function.

Comment: added the sample file to question.

Comment: 50 MB and 2962 items are very low numbers. You should see results in seconds, rather than hours. I too don't see why you need to do this in two passes. Post a [mcve] including input and the expected output to get a better answer.

Comment: OK, that's a start. What is the corresponding output?  If you want help you need to learn to provide sufficient information without us having to extract it from you piecemeal.

Comment: You mean that we can combine getting id, title and result in one XSL?

Comment: Ok, I thought that was obvious. Sorry about that. Basically, I need \n separated values for id, title and result from the source file.

Comment: If I understand you, you are running the first XSL to produce a list of IDs.  Then you are running the second XSL for every unique ID, i.e. 2962 separate invocations of the XSLT processor.  This is not good.  Show the final output you desire from the second XSL for the given input XML.

Comment: Please post the expected result of transforming the given example, so that we can test our results against that.

Comment: yes added the sample output to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work for you?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:oval-res="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-results-5"
xmlns:oval-def="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5"
exclude-result-prefixes="oval-def oval-res">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="result" match="oval-res:definition" use="@definition_id" />

<xsl:template match="/oval-res:oval_results">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="oval-def:oval_definitions/oval-def:definitions/oval-def:definition">
            <def>
                <RuleID>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
                </RuleID>       
                <Title>
                    <xsl:value-of select="oval-def:metadata/oval-def:title"/>
                </Title>
                <Status>
                    <xsl:value-of select="key('result', @id)/@result"/>
                </Status>
            </def>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For ease of testing, I have made this return an XML result. Applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <def>
      <RuleID>oval:com.vmware.test.linux:def:3</RuleID>
      <Title>Rule 3 - /etc/passwd file is group-owned by root</Title>
      <Status>true</Status>
   </def>
   <def>
      <RuleID>oval:com.vmware.test.linux:def:2</RuleID>
      <Title>Rule 2 - /etc/passwd file is owned by root</Title>
      <Status>true</Status>
   </def>
   <def>
      <RuleID>oval:com.vmware.test.linux:def:1</RuleID>
      <Title>Rule 1 - /etc/passwd file has permissions of 644 or more restrictive</Title>
      <Status>true</Status>
   </def>
</output>
```

Comment: Superb! Works like a charm!

Comment: @praving5 Out of curiosity: how long does it take now?

Comment: Could not even count! I think less than 5 seconds!

Comment: Michael, How do I do a similar thing for an XML file like http://pastebin.com/VbMhcxVk. In this again, I am  interested in picking idref, result, and title. I tried following your example, but could not do it. Please help.

Comment: @praving5 I suggest you post a new question and include the XML input example, your attempted XSLT and the expected result there.

Comment: Hi Michael, I opened a new thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38997209/xslt-improvement. Please check.