# XSLT improvement

Tags: xml, xslt

This is linked with [Can XSLT be improved further?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38989162/can-xslt-be-improved-further/38990027).

I have an XML as below:

**Sample XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Benchmark xmlns="http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" id="xccdf_com.vmware.linux_benchmark_file-test" resolved="1" xml:lang="en-US">
  <status date="2015-09-20">draft</status>
  <title xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US">Test content for file_test probe</title>
  <description xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US">File content for OVAL file file_test_content-oval.xml built on 2015-09-20T02:13:56</description>
  <platform idref="cpe:/o:sles11:linux"/>
  <version>v0.0</version>
  <model system="urn:xccdf:scoring:default"/>
  <Profile id="xccdf_com.vmware.linux_profile_test">
    <status date="2015-09-20">draft</status>
    <version update="1" time="2015-09-20T14:57:39.808+05:30">1.0</version>
    <title xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US">Test_Profile</title>
    <description xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">This is a test profile to test file_test probe.</description>
    <select idref="xccdf_com.vmware.linux_rule_test-def-3" selected="true"/>
    <select idref="xccdf_com.vmware.linux_rule_test-def-2" selected="true"/>
    <select idref="xccdf_com.vmware.linux_rule_test-def-1" selected="true"/>
  </Profile>
  <Group id="xccdf_com.vmware.linux_group_test" weight="1.000000">
    <platform idref="cpe:/o:sles11:linux"/>
    <Rule id="xccdf_com.vmware.linux_rule_test-def-3" selected="true" weight="1.000000" role="full" severity="unknown">
      <title xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US">Rule 3 - /etc/passwd file is group-owned by root</title>
      <description xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US">This rule verifies that /etc/passwd file is group-owned by root.</description>
      <check system="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5">
        <check-content-ref name="oval:com.vmware.test.linux:def:3" href="file_test_content-oval.xml"/>
      </check>
    </Rule>
    <Rule id="xccdf_com.vmware.linux_rule_test-def-2" selected="true">
      <title xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US">Rule 2 - /etc/passwd file is owned by root</title>
      <description xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US">This rule verifies that /etc/passwd file is owned by root.</description>
      <check system="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5">
        <check-content-ref name="oval:com.vmware.test.linux:def:2" href="file_test_content-oval.xml"/>
      </check>
    </Rule>
    <Rule id="xccdf_com.vmware.linux_rule_test-def-1" selected="true">
      <title xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US">Rule 1 - /etc/passwd file has permissions of 644 or more restrictive</title>
      <description xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US">This rule verifies that /etc/passwd file has permissions of 644 or more restrictive.</description>
      <check system="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5">
        <check-content-ref name="oval:com.vmware.test.linux:def:1" href="file_test_content-oval.xml"/>
      </check>
    </Rule>
  </Group>
  <TestResult id="xccdf_org.open-scap_testresult_xccdf_com.vmware.linux_profile_test" start-time="2016-08-17T13:38:29" end-time="2016-08-17T13:38:29" version="v0.0">
    <benchmark href="/tmp/tmp.VnFIMSRKhw/input.xml" id="xccdf_com.vmware.linux_benchmark_file-test"/>
    <title>OSCAP Scan Result</title>
    <identity authenticated="false" privileged="false"/>
    <profile idref="xccdf_com.vmware.linux_profile_test"/>
    <target>vROPS_6-1</target>
    <target-address>127.0.0.1</target-address>
    <target-address>127.0.0.2</target-address>
    <target-address>10.112.56.130</target-address>
    <target-address>0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1</target-address>
    <target-address>fe80:0:0:0:250:56ff:fe93:6159</target-address>
    <target-address>0:0:0:0:0:0:0:10.112.56.130</target-address>
    <target-address>0:0:0:0:0:0:0:127.0.0.2</target-address>
    <target-address>0:0:0:0:0:0:0:127.0.0.1</target-address>
    <target-facts>
      <fact name="urn:xccdf:fact:scanner:name" type="string">OpenSCAP</fact>
      <fact name="urn:xccdf:fact:scanner:version" type="string">1.2.5</fact>
      <fact name="urn:xccdf:fact:ethernet:MAC" type="string">00:00:00:00:00:00</fact>
      <fact name="urn:xccdf:fact:ethernet:MAC" type="string">00:00:00:00:00:00</fact>
      <fact name="urn:xccdf:fact:ethernet:MAC" type="string">00:50:56:93:61:59</fact>
      <fact name="urn:xccdf:fact:ethernet:MAC" type="string">00:00:00:00:00:00</fact>
      <fact name="urn:xccdf:fact:ethernet:MAC" type="string">00:50:56:93:61:59</fact>
      <fact name="urn:xccdf:fact:ethernet:MAC" type="string">00:00:00:00:00:00</fact>
      <fact name="urn:xccdf:fact:ethernet:MAC" type="string">00:00:00:00:00:00</fact>
      <fact name="urn:xccdf:fact:ethernet:MAC" type="string">00:00:00:00:00:00</fact>
    </target-facts>
    <platform idref="cpe:/o:sles11:linux"/>
    <rule-result idref="xccdf_com.vmware.linux_rule_test-def-3" role="full" time="2016-08-17T13:38:29" severity="unknown" weight="1.000000">
      <result>pass</result>
      <check system="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5">
        <check-content-ref name="oval:com.vmware.test.linux:def:3" href="file_test_content-oval.xml"/>
      </check>
    </rule-result>
    <rule-result idref="xccdf_com.vmware.linux_rule_test-def-2" time="2016-08-17T13:38:29" weight="1.000000">
      <result>pass</result>
      <check system="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5">
        <check-content-ref name="oval:com.vmware.test.linux:def:2" href="file_test_content-oval.xml"/>
      </check>
    </rule-result>
    <rule-result idref="xccdf_com.vmware.linux_rule_test-def-1" time="2016-08-17T13:38:29" weight="1.000000">
      <result>pass</result>
      <check system="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5">
        <check-content-ref name="oval:com.vmware.test.linux:def:1" href="file_test_content-oval.xml"/>
      </check>
    </rule-result>
    <score system="urn:xccdf:scoring:default" maximum="100.000000">100.000000</score>
  </TestResult>
</Benchmark>
```

Please note that Group and Profile element are **optional**. A valid **sample xml** could be one like below as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Benchmark xmlns="http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" id="xccdf_com.vmware.linux_benchmark_file-test" resolved="1" xml:lang="en-US">
  <status date="2015-09-20">draft</status>
  <title xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US">Test content for file_test probe</title>
  <description xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US">File content for OVAL file file_test_content-oval.xml built on 2015-09-20T02:13:56</description>
  <platform idref="cpe:/o:sles11:linux"/>
  <version>v0.0</version>
  <model system="urn:xccdf:scoring:default"/>
  <Rule id="xccdf_com.vmware.linux_rule_test-def-3" selected="true" weight="1.000000" role="full" severity="unknown">
    <title xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US">Rule 3 - /etc/passwd file is group-owned by root</title>
    <description xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US">This rule verifies that /etc/passwd file is group-owned by root.</description>
    <check system="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5">
      <check-content-ref name="oval:com.vmware.test.linux:def:3" href="file_test_content-oval.xml"/>
    </check>
  </Rule>
  <Rule id="xccdf_com.vmware.linux_rule_test-def-2" selected="true">
    <title xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US">Rule 2 - /etc/passwd file is owned by root</title>
    <description xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US">This rule verifies that /etc/passwd file is owned by root.</description>
    <check system="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5">
      <check-content-ref name="oval:com.vmware.test.linux:def:2" href="file_test_content-oval.xml"/>
    </check>
  </Rule>
  <Rule id="xccdf_com.vmware.linux_rule_test-def-1" selected="true">
    <title xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US">Rule 1 - /etc/passwd file has permissions of 644 or more restrictive</title>
    <description xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US">This rule verifies that /etc/passwd file has permissions of 644 or more restrictive.</description>
    <check system="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5">
      <check-content-ref name="oval:com.vmware.test.linux:def:1" href="file_test_content-oval.xml"/>
    </check>
  </Rule>
  <TestResult id="xccdf_org.open-scap_testresult_default-profile" start-time="2016-08-17T19:18:42" end-time="2016-08-17T19:18:42" version="v0.0">
    <benchmark href="/tmp/tmp.nMXPWBmAJO/input.xml" id="xccdf_com.vmware.linux_benchmark_file-test"/>
    <title>OSCAP Scan Result</title>
    <identity authenticated="false" privileged="false"/>
    <target>vRealizeClusterNode</target>
    <target-address>127.0.0.1</target-address>
    <target-address>127.0.0.2</target-address>
    <target-address>10.112.56.132</target-address>
    <target-address>0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1</target-address>
    <target-address>fe80:0:0:0:250:56ff:fe93:21b6</target-address>
    <target-facts>
      <fact name="urn:xccdf:fact:scanner:name" type="string">OpenSCAP</fact>
      <fact name="urn:xccdf:fact:scanner:version" type="string">1.2.5</fact>
      <fact name="urn:xccdf:fact:ethernet:MAC" type="string">00:00:00:00:00:00</fact>
      <fact name="urn:xccdf:fact:ethernet:MAC" type="string">00:00:00:00:00:00</fact>
      <fact name="urn:xccdf:fact:ethernet:MAC" type="string">00:50:56:93:21:B6</fact>
      <fact name="urn:xccdf:fact:ethernet:MAC" type="string">00:00:00:00:00:00</fact>
      <fact name="urn:xccdf:fact:ethernet:MAC" type="string">00:50:56:93:21:B6</fact>
    </target-facts>
    <platform idref="cpe:/o:sles11:linux"/>
    <rule-result idref="xccdf_com.vmware.linux_rule_test-def-3" role="full" time="2016-08-17T19:18:42" severity="unknown" weight="1.000000">
      <result>pass</result>
      <check system="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5">
        <check-content-ref name="oval:com.vmware.test.linux:def:3" href="file_test_content-oval.xml"/>
      </check>
    </rule-result>
    <rule-result idref="xccdf_com.vmware.linux_rule_test-def-2" time="2016-08-17T19:18:42" weight="1.000000">
      <result>pass</result>
      <check system="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5">
        <check-content-ref name="oval:com.vmware.test.linux:def:2" href="file_test_content-oval.xml"/>
      </check>
    </rule-result>
    <rule-result idref="xccdf_com.vmware.linux_rule_test-def-1" time="2016-08-17T19:18:42" weight="1.000000">
      <result>pass</result>
      <check system="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5">
        <check-content-ref name="oval:com.vmware.test.linux:def:1" href="file_test_content-oval.xml"/>
      </check>
    </rule-result>
    <score system="urn:xccdf:scoring:default" maximum="100.000000">100.000000</score>
  </TestResult>
</Benchmark>
```

I am interested in picking up `idref`, and corresponding `title` and `result`from both the above possible xmls.

The out put could be just plain text separated by `\n`.

I wrote XSL as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:cdf="http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.2"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    xmlns:db="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
    xmlns:s="http://open-scap.org/"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xsl cdf db s exsl"
    xmlns:ovalres="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-results-5"
    xmlns:sceres="http://open-scap.org/page/SCE_result_file"
    >

<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />

<xsl:key name="result" match="cdf:rule-result" use="@idref" />

<xsl:template match="/cdf:TestResult">
    <xsl:for-each select="cdf:rule-result">
        <xsl:value-of select="@idref" />
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="cdf:title"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('result', @idref)/result"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But, this isn't generating the desired output? What am I doing wrong here?

Please help.

Comment: Why are you starting at `TestResult/rule-result` and not at `Group/Rule` - as you did in the previous question? If you can just list the values of `rule-result` directly, there is no need to use the key.

Comment: And where is your expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several issues:

1. `TestResult` is not the root element, so your template:

   ```
   <xsl:template match="/cdf:TestResult">
   ```

   is never applied. The output that you see is produced purely by the
   [built-in template rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#built-in-rule).
2. `TestResult` has no `title` child, so your instruction:

   ```
   <xsl:value-of select="cdf:title"/>
   ```

   will not return anything.
3. When you do:

   ```
   <xsl:for-each select="cdf:rule-result">
   ```

   you are already in the context of `rule-result`, so your use of a key makes no sense. And you forgot to include the `cdf:` prefix on the `result`.

---

Based on your previous question, I would think you want to go over the `Rule` nodes under `Group` and get the linked `rule-result` from there, instead of going over `rule-result` nodes directly:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:cdf="http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.2">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />

<xsl:key name="result" match="cdf:rule-result" use="@idref" />

<xsl:template match="/cdf:Benchmark">
    <xsl:for-each select="cdf:Group/cdf:Rule">
        <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="cdf:title"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('result', @id)/cdf:result"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
xccdf_com.vmware.linux_rule_test-def-3
Rule 3 - /etc/passwd file is group-owned by root
pass
xccdf_com.vmware.linux_rule_test-def-2
Rule 2 - /etc/passwd file is owned by root
pass
xccdf_com.vmware.linux_rule_test-def-1
Rule 1 - /etc/passwd file has permissions of 644 or more restrictive
pass
```

Comment: Hi Michael, This is good, but group element is optional in this case. I would just want to pick @id from Rule irrespective of Group is there or not.

Comment: I am not sure I understand this correctly. If the `Group` is not there, will `Rule` be a direct child of `Benchmark`? If yes, you can change `<xsl:for-each select="cdf:Group/cdf:Rule">` to `<xsl:for-each select=".//cdf:Rule">` - but it will cost you in terms of performance.

Comment: Hi Michael, I have updated the question with both the possible source XMLs. Basically, profile and group elements are optional, but our XSL should work in both the cases. Both, are valid source XMLs.

Comment: Have you tried what I suggested? You may also want to try `<xsl:for-each select="cdf:Group/cdf:Rule | cdf:Rule">` to see if it's any faster

Comment: `XPath error : Invalid expression
cdf:Group/cd‌​f:Rule | cdf:Rule
            ^
compilation error: file get_xccdf_results.xsl line 16 element for-each
xsl:for-each : could not compile select expression 'cdf:Group/cd‌​f:Rule | cdf:Rule'`

Comment: @praving5 I suspect this is a copy/paste gremlins issue. Try typing the expression from scratch.

Comment: ah, ok. Yes, you are right! This works nicely. Thanks again Michael.

Answer (score 1):

First, to filter you result, just match the root node and apply only your desired node. such as

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="cdf:Benchmark/cdf:TestResult"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Second, you need to know about xpath axes (forward and backward). `cdf:title` is a preceding-sibling to the context node (`cdf:rule-result`). Third, you don't need keys to get `cdf:result`, just select it directly, thus:

```
<xsl:template match="cdf:TestResult">
    <xsl:for-each select="cdf:rule-result">
        <xsl:value-of select="@idref" />
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::cdf:title"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="cdf:result"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

and the whole stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:cdf="http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.2"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    xmlns:db="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
    xmlns:s="http://open-scap.org/"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xsl cdf db s exsl"
    xmlns:ovalres="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-results-5"
    xmlns:sceres="http://open-scap.org/page/SCE_result_file"
    >


    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="cdf:Benchmark/cdf:TestResult"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cdf:TestResult">
        <xsl:for-each select="cdf:rule-result">
            <xsl:value-of select="@idref" />
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::cdf:title"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="cdf:result"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

outputs:

```
xccdf_com.vmware.linux_rule_test-def-3
OSCAP Scan Result
pass
xccdf_com.vmware.linux_rule_test-def-2
OSCAP Scan Result
pass
xccdf_com.vmware.linux_rule_test-def-1
OSCAP Scan Result
pass
```

Comment: Hi Joel, Thanks, this is good. But, I need title. So, I think I should be giving just `cdf:title`? The output should be `xccdf_com.vmware.linux_rule_test-def-3
Rule 3 - /etc/passwd file is group-owned by root
pass
xccdf_com.vmware.linux_rule_test-def-2
Rule 2 - /etc/passwd file is owned by root
pass
xccdf_com.vmware.linux_rule_test-def-1
Rule 1 - /etc/passwd file has permissions of 644 or more restrictive
pass`

Comment: Now I see the use of the key. You can use Michael's answer.